# How to group android shortcuts inside a "folder"programatically in an android custom launcher application?

Tags: android, package, shortcut, launcher

I'm developing a custom launcher application and I'd like to group some apps inside a folder like the default launcher behavior of Android. I couldn't find some API to create this "folder" programatically.

I already tried to define the OnItemLongClick behavior but only this is not possible to group the icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> like the default launcher behavior of Android

There is no "default launcher" for Android. Across the tens of thousands of Android device models, there are several dozen pre-installed launcher implementations.

> I couldn't find some API to create this "folder" programatically.

That is not a feature of the operating system. You will need to store this information yourself in some sort of file managed by your app.

Comment: Ok, so I should implement this behavior of drag/drop icons to create a "view" that will be my folder ?

Comment: @lpcs: Yes, you will need to implement that as well, or however you wish to have users indicate what apps should go into the folder.

Comment: I'm using a List<AppInfo> elements to be used by recycler view in my adapter. Do you have any implementation/pattern suggestion about how to add this "folder" as the first element of the list, or at least of the GridLayoutManager?

Comment: @lpcs: I do not know what `AppInfo` is. Have a `List<LauncherItem>`, where `LauncherItem` is an `interface` for `AppInfo` and `FolderInfo`, or something like that.